# Laptop battery not charging after update?

Tags: battery

It shows I have 30 minutes left. The update involved kernels. I just don't know. I don't know if I'll have power or not in a half hour. Is there any way to roll back changes. What to do?

Comment: I really don't think updating the kernel will prevent you from charging your laptop battery.

Comment: Well, it's not charging. It was working fine until I pressed power and committed my updates. Coincidence? It's happening, likely or not. I have about 20 minutes left. If I take my battery out, my laptop gets no power from the adapter. I  might be toast in a few minutes

Comment: May be it's charging but it's not updating, i some time happens yo my PC, try restarting to make it update the charge data; or remove and place again the battery with the ac connected.

Comment: Whether the OS is causing this problem or not, if you turn off your computer and leave it off, or at an early screen in the boot process, your battery will definitely charge. (Unless it's an incredibly weird computer, in which case I'd encourage you to fire it into the sun).

If it isn't charging with the computer turned off, you have an odd coincidence and either a damaged laptop or a damaged power cable. Perhaps something overheated?

Answer (score 2):

I have had this issue for some time now.  With Ubuntu running, my battery would not charge.  I could leave it running and plugged in for hours.  Then, when I pull the plug, it complains about the battery being low.  If I leave it plugged in while the power is off it would charge just fine.

Recently, I installed Fedora for a time.  I never noticed any issues with charging while the OS was running.  I just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10, and I am noticing the same issue again.  Yesterday, the battery sat at 83% while I left it on.  It didn't start charging until I rebooted.

On older versions of Ubuntu, my solution was to start "upower".  I learned that if I put the "upower" command in the startup applications, that I wouldn't have the issue.  I haven't spent enough time on it with Ubuntu 11.10 yet to see if that works.  I would love to get this fixed though so I don't need a work around.