# My Laptop Battery Does Not Charge

Tags: 11.10, battery, power-management

I am using a HP Pavilion and Ubuntu 11.10. I have been using Ubuntu for about a year.

Recently (in Nov or there about), I noticed my battery never charges fully no matter how long it has been plugged in. I thought it was a problem with the power pack. However, after changing it, the problem is still persisting.

I upgraded to 11.10 form 11.04 at about the same time so I do not know if this is a software or hardware issue.

How do I solve this?

This problem has been written about in various forms

[Laptop battery not charging after update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72654/laptop-battery-not-charging-after-update).

Please help me or find someone that can.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you suspect its a software issue and that it never occurred in previous versions of ubuntu, I would boot your computer with a LiveCD of 10.04/10.10/11.04 and leave your power-pack plugged in.

If the problem persists this would indicate a hardware issue.

Comment: No one seems to know the answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/72654/laptop-battery-not-charging-after-update

Comment: ... did you do what I asked?  Does your power pack charge when booted from a live 10.04 cd?

Comment: 10.04? I am using 11.10.

Comment: I'm asking you to boot from a live CD - it doesnt matter what version - just anything other than 11.10. If you leave the machine plugged in whilst booted from the live CD, does your battery charge correctly?

Comment: Ok. I will do that now. I did not know what you meant. i.e, use another version without having to install it.

Comment: My internet is the slowest in the world so i will report back by tomorrow when the download gets completed.

Comment: If you happened have other liveCD to play with, use that. The point is to see either current version of Ubuntu caused that or it is a hardware issue. I would suspect that it is normally a hardware issue, battery dies eventually.

Comment: I have eventually downloaded and tried a live version (10.04). It says fully charged. however, when I unplug my battery, it goes to 21%. When I plug it back, it says battery full.

Comment: This definitely sounds more like a hardware issue - as pstar and oli have said - this is more like either a battery issue (likely) or a problem with the onboard power management stuff.  You mentioned in your question that you upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10.  I'm assuming that you have previously had 10.04 installed and you upgraded to 10.10 and then to 11.04?  If you never had 10.04 installed then it would be useful to double-check your observation with a 11.04 live CD... however it is looking more and more like a hardware issue :(

Comment: Thanks guys. I guess I will try to do the 11.04 live CD. The laptop is quite old though.

Comment: As this answer did not solve my problem but was the best answer, what am I to do?

Answer (score 1):

A fairly common feature in new (within two years old) laptops is a battery buffer that stops the battery filling right up to the top. They do this to preserve the overall lifespan of the battery. Have a look in the BIOS settings and see if there's anything suggesting that. There might also be a battery calibration test that can be done from BIOS.

If that's not the case, it could easily be hardware. It certainly does make sense to test the software but I've seen laptop batteries die a lot faster than 12 months from constant trickle-charging. You might want to step through what you can on [HP's help page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=c00259897&product=18703).